# Why can't we use @Cacheable with static method in spring with ehcache?

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache

I am new to Spring and read that we can't use `@Cacheable` with `static method` but can't found why we can't use so any one can explain so that beginner can understood easily?
Can we use static method for retrieving `database table`?
I have made `static method` of all method of `service layer` of DAO so Is this `thread-safe`?

Comment: You might find your answer [in this issue report](https://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/issues/detail?id=51) Quote from the link: "Static methods cannot be cached. The way aspects work in Spring is by adding a wrapper class (a proxy) to the annotated class. There is no way in Java to add a wrapper to a static method."

Comment: @CeilingGecko I had gone through that site but i can't understood so can you elaborate "The way aspects work in Spring is by adding a wrapper class (a proxy) to the annotated class. There is no way in Java to add a wrapper to a static method."?

Comment: I'll try to find a nice graphic I had in a Spring book, and will write up an answer, that is if someone doesn't beat me to it :P

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[image: Spring Aspect Concept]

Elaborating on my comment:

*"Static methods cannot be cached. The way aspects work in Spring is by adding a wrapper class (a proxy) to the annotated class. There is no way in Java to add a wrapper to a static method."*

Since Spring needs an object to wrap around in order to intercept calls to that object and perform various operations before delegating the modified input to the original object (thus spring aspects are possible).

Since anything that is `static` cannot be instantiated as an object, Spring has no way to wrap around it and intercept its calls (at least with the current implementation of Spring)

Comment: @CellingGecko , Thank you very much but still one question arise that why spring can't call static method in wrapper class(may be due to `static method can't be override`?).

Comment: @KamleshKanazariya The way this works in Spring is that the proxy object tries to "act" like the target so it must disguise itself as such, but since the static method is not bound to an object and is instead bound to the actual class (and class is just a blueprint which tells you how to create objects) the proxy object can't disguise itself as the target since it itself is an object, it just can't fool the caller telling him that it is the target because the caller knows that the target is not an object and the target sees that the proxy is an object.

Answer (score 4):

It is a limitation of the mechanism used to provide caching.

When you mark some method as `@Cacheable`, Spring creates a proxy to your bean that intercepts method invocations and provides the caching, and will inject that instead of the original bean. So if you have some code like:

```
@Inject
private MyBean myBean;
...
myBean.myMethod("foo");
```

where `MyBean` has declared `myMethod()` as `@Cacheable`, then `myBean` will not point to what you put in the application context, but to a proxy that will do the caching and invoke the original `MyBean.myMethod()` only when cache lookup does not return anything.

Proxys cannot intercept static methods, so the proxy cannot cache static methods. That is why `@Cacheable` will not work on static methods.

Comment: Ahh. nice explanation